# What's the best way to display associated data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have 3 models, Genotypes, Gmarkers and Gsamples,  associated in the following way:

```
class Genotype < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :allele1, :allele2, :run_date
  belongs_to :gmarkers
  belongs_to :gsamples
end

class Gmarker < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :marker
  has_many :genotypes, :dependent => :delete_all  
end

class Gsample < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :box, :labid, :subjectid, :well
  belongs_to :gupload
  has_many :genotypes, :dependent => :delete_all
end
```

When I display a list of the Gentypes (in index.html.erb), I'm displaying the related data in the following way:

```
<% @genotypes.each do |f| %>
  <tr>    
    <td><%= Gmarker.find(f.gmarkers_id).marker %></td>
    <td><%= Gsample.find(f.gsamples_id).labid %></td>
    <td><%= f.allele1 %></td>
    <td><%= f.allele2 %></td>
    <td><%= f.run_date %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', f %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_genotype_path(f) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', f, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

However, the page takes a while to load, so I'm wondering if there is an easier way to display the associated data without doing two lookups per loop. I could not get any associated data to show up using the built-in reference Rails style of something like:

```
f.GMarker.first.marker
```

But whenever I try that in the console, I get a slew of errors starting with

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Genotype::Gmarkers
```

I don't understand whey the console doesn't know about Gmarkers, since there is a one-to-many relationship between in their models....

Any help much appreciated!

--Rick

Answer (score 0):

In your Genotype class, change your belongs_to declaration to:

```
  belongs_to :gmarker
  belongs_to :gsample
```

then on your view (index.html.erb), replace the following code:

```
<td><%= Gmarker.find(f.gmarkers_id).marker %></td>
<td><%= Gsample.find(f.gsamples_id).labid %></td>
```

with this one:

```
<td><%= f.gmarker.marker %></td>
<td><%= f.gsample.labid %></td>
```